# Woher kommt die Redensart "eine Sau durchs Dorf treiben"?

Tags: phrase

Die Redensart und ihre Bedeutung sind mir an sich schon lange bekannt und glaubte bisher auch, die Herkunft sei relativ klar – ein Exemplar der Unterart [*Sus scrofa domestica*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausschwein) wird zum Spaß, oder um es nach seiner Flucht einzufangen, durch das Dorf getrieben; bald wird es eine andere Sau sein, mit der man das gleiche macht, und der Vorgang an sich ist nichts Besonderes.

Nun haben mich bezüglich der Harmlosigkeit dieser Redensart allerdings meine Zweifel beschlichen, da die ehrwürdige und in geschichtlichen sowie sprachlichen Zusammenhängen anscheinend recht beflissene Titanic diese Redensart [kürzlich in einen weniger harmlosen Zusammenhang gestellt](http://www.titanic-magazin.de/news.html?&tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=4687&cHash=0e0d1558e5b2f9d64db89c457a255962) hat.

Wann also ist diese Redensart entstanden, und hat sie früher etwas anderes oder Spezifischeres bedeutet als heute?

Comment: Ich glaube, dass es den selben Ursprung hat, wie einige andere Redensarten mit [*Sau*](http://www.redensarten.net/Sau+machen.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Du interpretierst zu viel in Titanic-Texte hinein ;)

Die Tiere mussten öfter bewegt werden, entweder vom Verkäufer zum Käufer, vom Bauern zum Markt, vom Markt zum Bauern, vom Züchter zum Schlachter und vom Schlachter … oh, warte …

Die Tiere wurden getrieben, weil das die einfachste und kostengünstigste Methode war. Und da wohl öfter eine arme Sau zur Schlachtbank getrieben wurde, hatte sich das bald als Redewendung eingebürgert.

Das [Medienkritik-Blog](http://medien-kritik.blogspot.com/2011/09/was-bedeutet-eine-sau-durchs-dorf-jagen.html) sieht es ähnlich.

Comment: Wobei mich die Spekulationen zur Lage von Bauernhöfen und Metzgereien/Schlachtereien in Dörfern in dem Blog auch nicht überzeugen. Früher haben 80% der Bevölkerung in der Landwirtschaft gearbeitet - zieht man also die Städter ab, so dürften 90% der Dörfer aus Bauernhöfen bestanden haben.

Answer (score 1):

Das war im 16. Jh. Belustigung. Ein Jungschwein wurde mit Öl eingerieben und "durchs Dorf getrieben". Die Dorfjugend lief johlend hinterher. Wem es trotzdem gelang das damals unerschwinglich teure Tier zu fangen, der durfte es behalten und "hat Schwein gehabt".

Comment: Das wäre eine schöne Antwort, wenn du einen Beleg für den Brauch geben könntest. Für mich hört sich das momentan noch an wie ein Zitat aus einem Terry-Pratchett-Roman

Comment: Ein Jungschwein wäre aber doch ein Ferkel, keine Sau, oder? Auch sehe ich da einen eklatanten Widerspruch, dass das Tier unerschwinglich teuer sein soll, es andererseits aber verschenkt wird. Dass der Brauch auch noch ein zweites Sprichwort begründen soll ist dann des Guten zu viel. Klingt wie ein Zitat von einer dieser Hoaxseiten, die sich alberne Herkunftserklärungen für Sprichwörter und Phrasen ausdenken. Wem geglaubt wird, der bekommt ein Marzipanschwein von den ARD-Faktenfindern geschenkt. Und wieso setzt Du "durchs Dorf getrieben" in Anführungsstriche? Ironie?

Answer (score 0):

Im übrigen wird meistens das Lamm zur Schlachtbank gebracht- laut Sprichwort. Und Lämmer sind ja so süß und unschuldig - weil klein und wehrlos. Aber eine richtige Sau ist nicht nur ziemlich dreckig, schnell und wendig, sondern manchmal gefährlich, sogar lebensgefährlich. Allerdings wurden die Säue in früheren Zeiten, so wie anderes Vieh auch, oft in den Wald getrieben, um dort zu fressen. Also geht´s nicht jeder armen Sau gleich, wenn sie durch Dorf getrieben wird, an den Kragen- oder den Hals. Das Sau-Treiben war eher ein alltägliches, etwas dörfliches und "anrüchiges" Geschäft- schätz´ ich.